# Sum in a specific year in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    date_start = DateField()
    date_end = DateField()
    amount = DecimalField()
```

The date range can go between years. Sometimes I want to sum the amount in a specific year.

I think that the only solution to this problem is to create another model B:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    year = IntegerField()
    month = IntegerField()
    amount = DecimalField()
```

and every time a `ModelA` object is saved I will iterate over the months between the start date and end date and create a `ModelB` object for each month with the amount divided by the number of days between the days times the number of days in the specific month.

Now I can get the amount sum with `ModelB.objects.filter(year=2014).aggregate(Sum('amount'))`.

I know how to do this, but is it the best solution? The execution time will be very high every time a `ModelA` object is changed and performance is an issue.

I think it's also necessary that I delete all `ModelB` objects before I create new objects, so the sum will be correct.

Comment: you mean you want to aggregate amount in year right ?. why are creating new model use this orm `ModelA.objects.filter(date_start__year=2014).aggregate(Sum('amount'))`

Comment: The start date and end date range between years, so the amount will be too big because a part of the amount should be in 2015, 2016 and so on

Comment: use where clause filter for between years, coming to performance use index based like solar, elastic engines.

Comment: see this it might be useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/